Synapse authentication error reading from ADLS gen2 when using trigger run
I have a notebook in azure synapse that I am using to read data from a storage account ADLS gen2. The notebook runs fine when I run it directly, but i get this error when I try to call the notebook from a pipeline. Does the pipeline runs use different authorization vs when I run the notebook directly? Thanks
An error occurred while calling o3571.load.
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.



An error occurred while calling o3571.load. java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

The Error Indicates that the operation you are trying to perform is not authorized due to insufficient permissions.
To work with a Synapse Analytics workspace configured with ADLS Gen2 as the default storage, you must have the Storage Blob Data Contributor role for the ADLS Gen2 filesystem.
I have assigned using the below steps:
Step 1: Go to Synapse Workspace resource and Go to Access control (IAM)
Step 2: Storage Blob Data Contributor role

Step 3: Grant the access storage Blob Contributor role to your  synapse workspace

Results:

